# Google chart ignores formatter

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I tried applying a formatter to a data table column but it is ignored.

```
function drawMultSeries(orderData) {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn('string', Translator.trans('company.dashboard.order_chart.days'));
    dataTable.addColumn('number', Translator.trans('company.dashboard.orders_title'));
    dataTable.addColumn('number', Translator.trans('company.dashboard.order_chart.expenses'));
    dataTable.addRows(orderData);


    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
        {prefix: 'test'});
    formatter.format(dataTable, 2);

    var options = {
        allowHtml: true,
        title: Translator.trans('company.dashboard.orders_title'),
        hAxis: {
            title: Translator.trans('company.dashboard.order_chart.days'),
            viewWindow: {
                min: [7, 30, 0],
                max: [17, 30, 0]
            }
        },
        vAxes: {
            1: { format: 'currency' }
        },
        colors: ['#8fd5ba', '#1C2C3A'],
        series: {
            0: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 0 },
            1: { type: 'area', targetAxisIndex: 1, areaOpacity: 0.07 }
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
        document.getElementById('chart-orders'));

    $('.dashboard-chart-loading').hide();
    $('#chart-orders').show();

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

[image]

I would expect the right side Axis to have "test" string prefixed to any value.

Answer (score 0):

You're formatting the data, hover over one of the data points on the line chart, you'll see the *test*.

To format the axis...

```
        vAxes: {
            1: { format: 'test $#,##0.00' }
        },
```

Example...

```js
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMultSeries);

    function drawMultSeries() {
        var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        dataTable.addColumn('string', 'days');
        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'title');
        dataTable.addColumn('number', 'expenses');
        dataTable.addRows([
          ['18/09', 1, 160],
          ['22/09', 1, 250]
        ]);

        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat(
            {prefix: 'test'});
        formatter.format(dataTable, 2);

        var options = {
            allowHtml: true,
            title: 'title',
            hAxis: {
                title: 'days',
                viewWindow: {
                    min: [7, 30, 0],
                    max: [17, 30, 0]
                },
            },
            vAxes: {
                1: { format: 'test $#,##0.00' }
            },
            colors: ['#8fd5ba', '#1C2C3A'],
            series: {
                0: { type: 'bars', targetAxisIndex: 0 },
                1: { type: 'area', targetAxisIndex: 1, areaOpacity: 0.07 }
            }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
            document.getElementById('chart-orders')
        );

        chart.draw(dataTable, options);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="chart-orders"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you but I used prefix 'test' as an example. In fact I want to use a custom formatter instead of the 'currency' provided by Google. In your code, there's no use for the "formatter" variable I guess.?

Comment: the purpose of the [formatter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#formatters) is to format the data, passed to the chart in `dataTable`. axis formats are provided in the chart `options`. in my example, I format the `vAxes` with `{ format: 'test $#,##0.00' }` --> which can be modified. I used currency based on the example.